# How to add the contents of a Stream containing XML into an existing XmlElement as a child?

Tags: c#, xml, stream, xmldocument

I have a `Stream` containing XML and I want to load its contents, then add its root element as a child to an existing `XmlElement`.  I know there is already `XmlDocument.Load(Stream stream);` but that will create a full, standalone XML document. Instead I would like to, given an existing `XmlDocument`, specify an element in that document to load the stream under.  Is this possible?

Comment: You have a stream and save it to XML. The given code does exactly the opposite: it saves an XML to a stream. What do you want?

Comment: yes you can select a node of the xml and save the stream to that node...something like that?

Comment: @Hackerman that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: You can do that with the method `SelectNodes` or the method `SelectSingleNode` with an xpath query, and replacing the innerText or the innerXml of the node with your value.

Comment: @dbc Maybe I misunderstood how `XmlDocument.Save` works. I *will* want to "convert" an xml element into a stream later, but currently I am concerned with the opposite: writing a stream to a specific xml element

Comment: @dbc Got it - so I was confused. Yes, I'd like to take a stream and "put it" (bad description) within a specified element within an already-existing XML document

Comment: @dbc yes, that looks good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the XML from a stream as the child of an existing `XmlElement`, you can first load the XML into an [`XmlDocumentFragment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocumentfragment(v=vs.110).aspx), then append the fragments, as follows:

```
// stream is an opened Stream containing a valid XML document
// xmlElement is an xmlElement 
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    var fragment = xmlElement.OwnerDocument.CreateDocumentFragment();
    using (var writer = fragment.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
    {
        writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
    }
    foreach (var child in fragment.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().ToList())
        xmlElement.AppendChild(child);
}
```

This solution is memory efficient in that it avoids loading the entire XML into a temporary string for parsing, instead chaining together an XML reader and writer using [`XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b.aspx).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7diixY).